# Can't parse JSonObject with Float.ParseFloat/valueOf

Tags: java, android, json

```java
String Qty = jsonobject.getString("QtyProduct");
float calc_qty = qtyFind - Float.parseFloat(Qty);
```

Then I get this

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,5"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
```

Please help me to fix this, is this a bug or what?

Comment: Well, the standard says that the decimal separator is a dot and not a comma. I _assume_ (because you didn't show the json) that in the json the value is a string and not a number because otherwise the json would be invalid. So you'd need to use `NumberFormat` to parse the number and define the locale or decimal separator accordingly.

Comment: An example of parsing `"1,5"` to `float` would be this (I'm using the German locale because it also defines the decimal separator to be a comma): `float value = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("1,5").floatValue();`.

Comment: you know what? you save my day!! thankyou very much!!!